# Rails - update multiple active record relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing an update all to a Model to update several ActiceRecord Relations.

But I want to skip an attribute if its not provided (if its nil or empty I dont want to update that attribute)

```
   def update_numbers(numbers, comment)
      numbers.update_all (number_status: Number::STATUS_UPDATED, comment: comment if void_comment.present?)
    end
```

This obviously does not work as it doesn't like the if condition.  Is there a way to not try and update comment if its `.blank?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
def update_numbers(numbers, comment)
  hash = { number_status: Number::STATUS_UPDATED }
  hash[:comment] = comment if comment.present?

  numbers.update_all hash
end
```